# How to insert a pre-trained model inside a model to train?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, pre-trained-model

I'm trying to build a deep-learning model in Keras. In this model, I want to insert some copies of a "pre-trained unit". This unit corresponds to a Keras model `model_1`, whose parameters I optimazed at an earlier stage.

Now I want to properly define `model_2` (to train) such that it includes some copies of `model_1`. The final layout of `model_2` will be [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWY0v.png), where each box contains a copy of `model_1`
and the red connections correspond to parameters extracted from pre-training.
Thus, the weights and biases associated with the red connections are known numbers.
I want to train `model_2` by keeping **fixed** these parameters and optimizing the other parameters (i.e. weights and biases associated with the black connections).

I have not found any similar example in literature. Is it possible to realize such a Neural Network architecture by using Keras? How can I properly define `model_2`?

Of course, I can manually extract the pre-trained parameters `par` (as a `numpy.array`)  from `model_1` and put them into `model_2`, by using something like `model_2.set_weights(par)`. The problem is that I have very large numbers of neurons/parameters. This means that Python is unable to allocate memory for a numpy.array of such dimensions.

Comment: Please re-open the question. The question is valid and clear and can be resolved with a good solution that might be useful for other users.

Comment: @OP, if you still have this unsolved, please re-post this question and i can help you with a solution.

Comment: Do message the link here if you re-post it. so that I can get find it easily.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal do you mean doing another post with the same question?

Comment: yes, but with slightly more detail.